# Encrypt / Decrypt Text in MySQL Column with PHP

Tags: php, php-5.3, mcrypt

I have to store some information (Text) in an MySQL Column (MediumBLOB). It works but I am not sure if this way is secure enough.

Please don't wonder that the encryption key is randomized. It works as designed :)

```
    $encryptionKeyRandom = str_random(12);
    $iv = mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB), MCRYPT_RAND);

    $encrypted_string = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $encryptionKeyRandom, $input['item'], MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv);
    $input['item'] = bin2hex($encrypted_string);
    // Save to DB
```

Suggestions for better security/encryption are welcome.

Comment: Well the security depends on how the key is stored. Despite your note, the fact you are using a random key is kind of worrying!

Answer (score 1):

mcrypt is outdated and hasn't been touched in quite a few years.
I'm not saying that it isn't useable, just that there are faster alternatives available cause quite frankly, mcrypt is slow.

openssl is a better alternative and works much like mcrypt, but the best library is in my opinion sodium. However sodium is not yet available in php 7 and maybe bringing it to 7.1. but should be for other versions.

https://www.virendrachandak.com/techtalk/encryption-using-php-openssl/ helped me migrating from mcrypt to openssl, take a look.